# JQuery Click Event Not Firing Alert

Tags: jquery, html

The click event below isn't firing, could someone please help?

```
<input type="button" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" value="Say Hallo!" />
```

```
$(document).ready($("#btnSave").click(function () {

    alert('Hallo!');

}));
```

Comment: Syntax is incorrect use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qL230vL/#&togetherjs=8TwHR9x6mF)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does, you need fix it your implementation.

You have defined the `event` handler `click` instead it expects a `function`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnSave").click(function () {
      alert('Hallo!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" value="Say Hallo!" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has syntax errors, you should put your code inside the closure method of `.ready(function() {  ...   here ..... })` method like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // <----- Closure method
  $("#btnSave").click(function () {
    alert('Hallo!');
  });
});
```

See more about [jQuery's `ready()` method](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() { // <----- Closure method
  $("#btnSave").click(function () {
    alert('Hallo!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSave">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
       alert('Hallo!');
    });
});
```

Comment: explanation would help the OP to understand what was wrong

Comment: You have used syntax error function to run after the document is loaded

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work fine for both static and dynamic elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click','#btnSave',function () {
   alert('Hello!');
});
```

});